# Is this function continuous on $[0, 250]$? Is it differentiable?

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Consider
$$
I(X)=\begin{cases}
15X & 0≤X≤150\\
22.5X-0.05X^2 & 150<X≤250
\end{cases}
$$

1. Is $I(x)$ continuous on $[0, 250]$?
2. Is $I(x)$ differentiable on $[0, 250]$?

THANKS!!

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find a question that looks like it consists only of a verbatim quote from an exercise sheet to be rude when asking for help; please consider adding your thoughts about this problem.

Comment: Moreover, for some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint for continuity:

1. Compute $I(150)=15 \times 150$;
2. Compute $\lim_{X \to 150+} 22.5X-0.05X^2$;
3. Check if the results of 1. and 2. coincide.

If $I$ is continuous, then you could check similarly if it is also differentiable.